# Average sum in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
  DataArray = [{
    "Year": "Year 7",
        "test1": 28,
        "test2": 19,
         "test3": 22,
         "average": ''

}, {
    "Year": "Year 8",
        "test1": 15,
        "test2": 28,
        "test3": 22,
        "average": ''           

}, {
    "Year": "Year 9",
        "test1": 25,
        "test2": 24,
         "test3": 22,
        "average": ''
 }, {
    "Year": "Year 10",
        "test1": 26,
        "test2": 19,
         "test3": 22,
        "average": ''            
}, {
    "Year": "Year 11",
        "test1": 48,
        "test2": 52,
         "test3": 22,
        "average": ''            
}];
```

How can I make it so that the  value of 'average' is the average of test 1, test 2, and test 3 in each object?

Comment: Erm ... Calculate it?! Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: you can't calculate it within the declaration since you can't reference the other properties within the declaration. You'll need to loop through it afterwards and do some math to calculate, e.g. `Math.round((DataArray[x].test2+DataArray[x].test3+DataArray[x].test1)/3)` where `x` is the current iteration of the loop. Note: it would probably be better if you put combined your `testN` properties into a single array

Comment: What's the actual problem here? You don't know how to loop? To add? To divide?

Answer (score 6):

```
dataArray.forEach(function(x) { x.average = (x.test1 + x.test2 + x.test3)/3 });
```

Will only work on [browsers that support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) `forEach`  which should be most modern browsers.

Also note that `dataArray` should be `camelCase` it is a **highly** recommended naming convention in javascript for everything to start with a lower case except for functions that should be invoked with `new`.

Comment: There's a polyfill at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if it's needed.

Comment: Deleted comment asked: "Where does forEach come from?" Answer is: It's a member of Array.prototype and is supported on every browser > IE8. If you need earlier support it could be a good idea to use polyfills like those from sugar.js, or libraries like underscore, or lodash

Comment: I guess I should correct myself that sugar.js isn't technically for polyfills. but does employ very similar techniques.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to support earlier than IE 9 you could do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0, data; i < DataArray.length; i ++) {
    data = DataArray[i];
    data.average = (data.test1 + data.test2 + data.test3) / 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a simple loop:

```
var avg = 0;
for(i in DataArray) {
    avg = DataArray[i]["test1"] + DataArray[i]["test2"] + DataArray[i]["test3"];
    DataArray[i]["average"] = avg / 3;
    alert(DataArray[i]["average"]);
}
```

Comment: Why reference things using `["string indexers"]`? This has no benefit

Comment: It was the first thing that I could think of. I just wanted to show how to do it through the loop.. Of course there are "cleanest" ways of doing this..

Comment: If you're going to do this, please `var` your `i` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea, as everybody else noted.  I've used jQuery to output the values to screen.  Otherwise, it is not needed in this solution.

```
dataArray.forEach(function (e, i) {

    var average = Math.floor((e.test1 + e.test2 + e.test3) / 3);

    $('<span />', {
        text: e.test1 + ' + ' + e.test2 + ' + ' + e.test3 + ' / = ' + average
    }).appendTo('body');

    e.average = average;
});

console.log(dataArray);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6FGg/